# how to create coupon code in magento only for admin created order?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to show discount just only when  admin create order but not show on fornt end how can I achieve this?

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3903/admin-only-coupon-code

Answer (score 1):

If you want the price to be discounted at checkout for admin only then you can do the following:

1. Create a Shopping Cart Price Rule from the promotions tab
2. Add Rule Name and select website
3. Select Admin for the Customer Groups option
4. In the actions tab select the discount amount and save.

Done.